# Full File Path vs. Short OSX

Tags: python, macos, file, io

I'm running OSX Mavericks but this problem has been going on since I had Snow Leopard.

When writing a script in any language, eg: Python. When I try to open a file the short
form doesn't work.

```
file = open('donkey.jpg')
```

And I get this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'donkey.jpg'
```

Instead, I always have to specify the full path.

```
file = open('/Users/myName/Desktop/donkey.jpg')
```

Any ideas on why this could be happening and how to correct it?

Comment: In your example, is the script located in `/Usrs/myName/Desktop/`?

Comment: Yes, both reside in the same directory. Also, the same instruction works in other computers, except for mine. @warunsl

Comment: @falsetru       PLACEHOLDER

Comment: What is the output of following command: `python -c 'import os; print(os.getcwd())'`. (Run the command in the same directory you run the script.)

Comment: Output: /Users/patriciojeri/Dropbox/Year 4/Term 2/CPSC 425/Assignment 4/assign

Answer (score 2):

If you specify `donkey.png`, it means `donkey.jpg` file in the current working directory. (relative path)

Make sure you're running the script in the same directory where  `donkey.jpg` exists.

If you want specify the image file path relative to the script file instead of current working directory use following:

```
import os

filepath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'donkey.jpg')
```

**NOTE** You can use `__file__` only in script file. (not in interactive mode)

Comment: NameError: name '\_\_file\_\_' is not defined

Comment: @geowar, You can't use `__file__` in interactive mode. To use `__file__`, you should save the file and run it.

Comment: @geowar, I updated the answer accordingly. Thank you for comment.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good work around the problem. However, what intrigues me is that you can use the relative path in other machines by just typing file = open('donkey.jpg') and that will default to looking for donkey.jpg in the current directory.

Comment: @PatricioJerí, How do you launch the script? Run in terminal? Double click the script icon? or something else?  According to how you launch the script, current working directory may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Your [open](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) call does not have a mode parameter. In which case, it defaults to opening the file in read mode.

Unless the file you are opening (to read) resides in the current working directory, it is completely expected that the python script throws a `IOError`.